# GPU/RAM out of Memory PyTorch/Transformers

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers

Context: I have six 3070 tis (48gb vram) and 8gb-32gb of ram along with 150gb ssd storage on my ubuntu 20.0.4 desktop. I am attempting to fine-tune [meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf](https://huggingface.co/meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf) with a very small dataset as a proof-of-concept. I took the first few entries from [this dataset on kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/dsxavier/diagnoise-me).

When I was initially running my script utilizing DataParallel with 8gb of ram, I would run out of memory and it would fail (no surprise). I added a few sticks to get me up to 32gb and was finally met with this error

> torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate
> 64.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacty of 7.58 GiB of which 17.88 MiB is free. Including non-PyTorch memory, this process has 7.53 GiB memory
> in use. Of the allocated memory 7.37 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and
> 5.71 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid
> fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and
> PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

Using `glances` I saw that it was only using my first GPU, rather than spreading the tasks out to all of them. I decided to try my hand at using DistributedDataParallel instead and ended up running out of memory even with 32gb.

I know there are many ways to optimize training/fine-tuning, which is why I came here for help. Would you recommend ZeRO, DP, DDP, PP, TP, or a combination of them such as in case 3 in the [huggingface documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/perf_train_gpu_many)? [Accelerate](https://huggingface.co/docs/accelerate/index)? [Optimum](https://huggingface.co/docs/optimum/index) (NVIDIA or others)? [TrainingArguments](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/perf_train_gpu_one)?

There are just so many different options and I'd love for someone to point me in the right direction and give an example of some working code I could test on my computer. To recreate environment:

```bash
mkdir test && cd test
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install torch transformers
# create file
# download dataset to same directory
```

Here is the almost working python code for just DP

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torch.optim import AdamW
import json

# Load dataset from JSON file
with open('small_en_medical_dialog.json', 'r') as file:
    dataset = json.load(file)

# Format the data
formatted_data = []
for item in dataset:
    input_text = "Description: " + item["Description"] + " Patient: " + item["Patient"]
    target_text = item["Doctor"]
    formatted_data.append({"input": input_text, "target": target_text})

# Define the custom Dataset class
class DoctorPatientDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, tokenizer, max_length=512):
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.data = data
        self.max_length = max_length

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = self.data[idx]
        input_encoding = self.tokenizer(
            item['input'],
            truncation=True,
            padding='max_length',
            max_length=self.max_length,
            return_tensors='pt'
        )
        target_encoding = self.tokenizer(
            item['target'],
            truncation=True,
            padding='max_length',
            max_length=self.max_length,
            return_tensors='pt'
        )
        return {
            'input_ids': input_encoding['input_ids'].flatten(),
            'attention_mask': input_encoding['attention_mask'].flatten(),
            'labels': target_encoding['input_ids'].flatten()
        }

# Initialize the model and tokenizer
model_name = "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
# Set padding token if not already set
if tokenizer.pad_token is None:
    tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.to(device)
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)

# Training setup
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=5e-5)
num_epochs = 3

# Create dataset and DataLoader
train_dataset = DoctorPatientDataset(formatted_data, tokenizer)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=3, shuffle=True)

# Training loop
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    total_loss = 0
    for batch in train_dataloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(input_ids=batch['input_ids'],
                        attention_mask=batch['attention_mask'],
                        labels=batch['labels'])
        loss = outputs.loss
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        total_loss += loss.item()
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}, Loss: {total_loss/len(train_dataloader)}")

# Save the fine-tuned model
model.module.save_pretrained("my_finetuned_model")

# Inference
model.eval()
query = "Hello, how are you?"
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(query, return_tensors='pt')
with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(input_ids=input_ids)
    response_ids = output.logits.argmax(-1)
    response = tokenizer.decode(response_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)

print(response)
```

Comment: The problem is related to the amount of GPU ram. System ram is not relevant

Comment: @Karl okay! Do you have any recommendations for splitting tasks up into smaller bits or making sure it shares it between all GPUs? I think an issue is that the model doesn't fit on a single GPU if I am understanding correctly.

Comment: What I would suggest you is implementing data parallelism. That means that you split your data on your six GPUs and and perform your learning there. For pytorch, you can use the [distributedDataParallel](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html) or DataParallel depending on how deep you want to go,